# How do i use zend_layout in boostrap

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am beginner.I have the following div structure in zend layout.phtml

```
<div id='outer'>//start outer
<div id='header'>//start header......</div>// end header
<div id='content'>//start content......</div>// end content
<div id='footer'>//start footer......</div>// end footer
</div>// end outer
```

Here i want to separate the page like header.phtml for header part and footer.phtml for footer part. How can i use zend_layout in bootsrap file for the above structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your bootstrap file:

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc(array('layoutPath' => 'PATH TO YOUR LAYOUT DIRECTORY'));
```

**EDIT:**

To separate header and footer in distinct files use this code:

```
<div id='outer'>//start outer
    <?php echo $this->render('header.phtml'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->render('content.phtml'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml'); ?>
</div>// end outer
```

Comment: here where do i add above code in bootstrap file ? Do we have add that in _initViewHelper()? if yes , my layout.phtml path is "application/layouts/scripts" Do i need to give that path in PATH TO YOUR LAYOUT DIRECTORY?

Comment: Add it to runApp() method. specify your layout path as i mentioned in the reply.

Comment: i got the point now, I used "zf enable layout" which add "resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/" in application.ini so i do not want to point again in bootsrap file about layout path...right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to fill these DIVs with their respective content contained in different files. You can do it in view something like this:

```
<div id='outer'>
   <div id='header'><?= $this->render('header.phtml'); ?></div>
   <div id='content'><?= $this->render('content.phtml'); ?></div>
   <div id='footer'><?= $this->render('footer.phtml'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Here you can manage **header.phtml**, **content.phtml** and **footer.phtml** separately.

Comment: I am using this way now,but why do we need to Zend_Layout::startMvc in bootstrap file

Comment: @Dinesh: You don't need to do anything in bootstrap for this solution. But make sure your files paths should be correct.